# error tikz graph reference (??)

Tags: cross-referencing

I don't know why appear this in my code
[image]

This is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

    \begin{ejemplo}

    Hallemos los extremos de  $(x^2+y^2)e^{-x^2-y^2}$. véase figura \ref{parw}

 \begin{figure}[htb]

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            width=0.5\linewidth,
            xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$
            ]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2]
            {((x^2+y^2)*exp(-x^2-y^2))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \label{parw}
    \caption{}
    \end{figure}
\end{ejemplo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\label` has to be placed *after* the `\caption`. Edit: and you have to compile the document twice.

Comment: My dear @TorbjørnT. You are on fire! Thanks so much